# Can't boot (freeze after a "/dev/sda5 clean ..." message) after upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot, upgrade, 16.04

After upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, boot stop after display this message:

> /dev/sda5: clean, 656424/656424 files, 4906392/... (unreadeable on my photo)

If i choose recovery mode, then select "resume" in recovery mode menu: some logs appears again. Then recovery log appear, i select again "resume". Log appear with this:

[image]

Then Ubuntu start normally. What's can i do ?

My /var/log/boot.log:

```
Starting Unattended Upgrades Shutdown...
[  OK  ] Stopped Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Bluetooth.
[  OK  ] Stopped Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
[  OK  ] Stopped IIO Sensor Proxy service.
[  OK  ] Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
[  OK  ] Stopped Bluetooth service.
[  OK  ] Stopped Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[  OK  ] Stopped Manage Sound Card State (restore and store).
[  OK  ] Stopped target Graphical Interface.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Multi-User System.
[  OK  ] Stopped Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
[  OK  ] Stopped crash report submission daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped Login Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped Thermal Daemon Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped Snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
[  OK  ] Stopped Regular background program processing daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
[  OK  ] Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
[  OK  ] Stopped Modem Manager.
[  OK  ] Stopped Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Stopped System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Stopped getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available.
[  OK  ] Stopped Getty on tty1.
[  OK  ] Removed slice system-getty.slice.
[  OK  ] Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
[  OK  ] Stopped PostgreSQL Cluster 9.3-main.
[  OK  ] Stopped Run anacron jobs.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Start the GNUstep distributed object mapper.
[  OK  ] Stopped Light Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[  OK  ] Stopped Accounts Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: start Winbind daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
         Starting Show Plymouth Reboot Screen...
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[  OK  ] Stopped PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main.
[  OK  ] Removed slice system-postgresql.slice.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Stopped Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: start Samba daemons for the AD DC.
[  OK  ] Stopped Cgroup management proxy.
[  OK  ] Stopped Cgroup management daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Stopped Restore /etc/resolv.conf if...fore the ppp link was shut down.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Timers.
[  OK  ] Stopped Daily apt activities.
[  OK  ] Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Stopped Timer to automatically refresh installed snaps.
[  OK  ] Stopped target System Time Synchronized.
[  OK  ] Stopped Hold until boot process finishes up.
[  OK  ] Stopped Permit User Sessions.
[  OK  ] Stopped target User and Group Name Lookups.
[  OK  ] Stopped /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
         Starting Set console scheme...
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Start/stop sysstat's sadc.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd).
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: start Samba NetBIOS nameserver (nmbd).
[  OK  ] Stopped target Network is Online.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Network.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Manager Wait Online.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Manager.
[  OK  ] Stopped D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Stopping Raise network interfaces...
[  OK  ] Stopped target Remote File Systems.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[  OK  ] Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Paths.
[  OK  ] Stopped Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Stopped ACPI Events Check.
[  OK  ] Stopped Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
[  OK  ] Stopped Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Slices.
[  OK  ] Removed slice User and Session Slice.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Closed ACPID Listen Socket.
[  OK  ] Closed Unix socket for apport crash forwarding.
[  OK  ] Closed Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Closed Docker Socket for the API.
[  OK  ] Closed Syslog Socket.
[  OK  ] Closed UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Closed Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Closed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Closed CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Stopped target System Initialization.
         Stopping Load/Save Screen Backlight...ness of backlight:acpi_video0...
[  OK  ] Stopped target Encrypted Volumes.
         Stopping Network Time Synchronization...
         Stopping Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
         Stopping Load/Save Random Seed...
[  OK  ] Stopped target Swap.
[  OK  ] Deactivated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/...ae7-87d7-4788-88f8-3fc2f742dc5c.
[  OK  ] Stopped Load/Save Random Seed.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Stopped Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Stopped Create Volatile Files and Directories.
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Reboot Screen.
[  OK  ] Stopped Load/Save Screen Backlight ...htness of backlight:acpi_video0.
[  OK  ] Removed slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
[  OK  ] Started Set console scheme.
[  OK  ] Stopped Raise network interfaces.
[  OK  ] Stopped Apply Kernel Variables.
[  OK  ] Stopped Load Kernel Modules.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Local File Systems.
         Unmounting /home...
[  OK  ] Unmounted /home.
[  OK  ] Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
[  OK  ] Stopped File System Check on /dev/d...28b-d9f2-4f77-b2fb-869c9ca50608.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
[  OK  ] Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[  OK  ] Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[  OK  ] Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[  OK  ] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Reached target Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Reached target Final Step.
         Starting Reboot...
```

My /var/log/dmseg : http://sk.bux.fr/~bux/dmesg

sudo fdisk -l:

```
Disque /dev/ram0 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram1 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram2 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram3 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram4 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram5 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram6 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram7 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram8 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram9 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram10 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram11 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram12 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram13 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram14 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/ram15 : 64 MiB, 67108864 octets, 131072 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disque /dev/mmcblk0 : 3,8 GiB, 4075290624 octets, 7959552 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Périphérique   Amorçage Start     Fin Secteurs  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *         8192 7959551  7951360  3,8G  b W95 FAT32


Disque /dev/sda : 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 octets, 488397168 secteurs
Unités : sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 octets
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x721a67f8

Périphérique Amorçage     Start       Fin  Secteurs   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1    *             2048   1023999   1021952   499M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2               1024000 171489279 170465280  81,3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3             171491326 488396799 316905474 151,1G  5 Étendue
/dev/sda5             171491328 254924799  83433472  39,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6             254926848 472705023 217778176 103,9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7             472707072 488396799  15689728   7,5G 82 partition d'échange Linux / Solaris
```

sudo blkid

```
/dev/mmcblk0: PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/mmcblk0p1: TYPE="vfat"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="BDEDrive" UUID="48A2B4A2A2B49642" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="721a67f8-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="OSDisk" UUID="8230B75030B749C5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="721a67f8-02"
/dev/sda5: UUID="4c893842-abf0-4bd2-897a-c15e85418ef4" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="721a67f8-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="a905e28b-d9f2-4f77-b2fb-869c9ca50608" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="721a67f8-06"
/dev/sda7: UUID="48cecbab-5a5f-4537-8214-83f8f445e4d0" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="721a67f8-07"
```

cat /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=4c893842-abf0-4bd2-897a-c15e85418ef4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=a905e28b-d9f2-4f77-b2fb-869c9ca50608 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=34e94ae7-87d7-4788-88f8-3fc2f742dc5c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Please add sudo fdisk -l, sudo blkid, and /etc/fstab. It looks like you have a disk problem, maybe sda6. Please describe disk configuration.

Comment: @heynnema hi, i just add disks infos

Comment: @heynnema you got it ! /etc/fstab try to mount wrong UUID for swap partition. It's now fixed ! Do you want write answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the UUID's shown in sudo blkid with your /etc/fstab configuration, and edit fstab as necessary. Glad you got it going!